# How to display CAN BUS information on EPS32 web server?

Tags: wifi, communication, esp32, web-server, can-bus

I try to display the transmitted information from CAN bus on ESP32 web server. I saved the `CAN.read()` in a buffer `receivedChars[i]` and try to display the data by  `client.println(receivedChars[i]);}`. However, nothing shows on the webserver... The complete code shows below,

```
// Copyright (c) Sandeep Mistry. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

#include <CAN.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "NGW_2.4G";
const char* password = "NextGW2018";

// Set webserver port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for (;;);
  }
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);

  Serial.println("CAN Receiver");
  CAN.setPins(16, 17);
  // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
  if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
    Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    while (1);
  }


  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

    char receivedChars[10];
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = CAN.parsePacket();

  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received ");

    if (CAN.packetExtended()) {
      Serial.print("extended ");
    }

    if (CAN.packetRtr()) {
      // Remote transmission request, packet contains no data
      Serial.print("RTR ");
    }

    Serial.print("packet with id 0x");
    Serial.print(CAN.packetId(), HEX);

    if (CAN.packetRtr()) 
    {
      Serial.print(" and requested length ");
      Serial.println(CAN.packetDlc());
    } 
    else 
    {
      Serial.print(" and length ");
      Serial.println(packetSize);

      // only print packet data for non-RTR packets
      while (CAN.available()) 
      {
         for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
         {
           receivedChars[i] = (char)CAN.read(); 
           Serial.print(receivedChars[i]);
         }      
      }
      Serial.println();
    }

    Serial.println();
  }

   WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients
   if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();

            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // CSS to style the table 
            client.println("<style>body { text-align: center; font-family: \"Trebuchet MS\", Arial;}");
            client.println("table { border-collapse: collapse; width:35%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }");
            client.println("th { padding: 12px; background-color: #0043af; color: white; }");
            client.println("tr { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 12px; }");
            client.println("tr:hover { background-color: #bcbcbc; }");
            client.println("td { border: none; padding: 12px; }");
            client.println(".sensor { color:white; font-weight: bold; background-color: #bcbcbc; padding: 1px; }");

            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("</style></head><body><h1>Can bus</h1>");
            client.println("<tr><td>text: </td><td><span class=\"sensor\">");


         for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
         {
           receivedChars[i] = (char)CAN.read();
           client.println(receivedChars[i]);           
         }  

            client.println(" .</span></td></tr>");  

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CAN-BUS can not be activated in web server session, I save the transmitted information in a buffer before starting the web server session, and print out the information from the buffer.